# Cannot figure out why my code for a random location button isn't working (python, pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Everything makes sense in my head. I don't understand why when I click on the button it does not work. I believe the problem is in these text lines

```
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if mouse[0] >= rand_x <= player_size and mouse[1] >= rand_y <= player_size:
            sys.exit()"""
```

[Python Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYtWD.png)

Comment: If you believe that is where your problem is, have you printed out the value of mouse?  What did you get?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please clarify what you mean by 'does not work'.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement:

```
mouse[0] >= rand_x <= player_size
```

what you are really saying is:

```
mouse[0]>= rand_X and rand_x <= player_size
```

So if rand_x is not lower or equal than player_size (50) it wont evaluate to True.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) says:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

Maybe what you meant is:

```
    rand_x <= mouse[0] <= rand_x+player_size
```